# PYTHON Sort only lowercase letters in place and don't sort numbers

Tags: python, sorting, uppercase, lowercase

I have to write a code where the user inputs numbers, lowercase letters and uppercase letters. They must then be sorted and printed. The tricky part is that the numbers must stay where they are inputted and must not be sorted. The lowercase letters must be sorted but only stay in places where lower cases were originally inputted. The UPPERCASE letters must also be sorted but only stay in places where UPPERCASE were originally inputted. I know that sounds confusing but here's and example:

The input string:

```
asDaA34sFcCdWt61
```

The output string should be:

```
aaAcC34dDsFsWt61
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
x = input("Enter the variables to be sorted: ")
z = list(x)
z.sort()
print(z)
```

I have tried everything within my knowledge to no luck. Please help; I am an amateur at best and could use lots of help.

Comment: Formatting your code properly would be a good start to getting help...

Comment: @Shadow, thank you. I changed it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  In particular, you've shown no attempt whatsoever to identify the three classes of characters in your problem: upper-case, lower-case, and other stuff.  Give us your best attempt as a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- *then* we have something to work on together.

Answer (score 0):

use `raw_input` instead `input`

`input` treat your input data as code, while `raw_input` as a string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
x = input("Enter the variables to be sorted: ")
listofletters = []
for y in range len(x):
    if x[y].islower() and x[y].isalpha():
        listofletters.append(x[y])
print(listofletters)
```

.islower checks if it is lower, and .isalpha checks if it is alpha, or a letter.
I have not tested this, but it should work